# Can't get two divs to align horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm pulling my hair out trying to get two div tags to align.  I've read page after page of solutions on here but I've not been able to get any of them to work.  I'm not sure if this is related to this being a Visual Studio project using MVC.  It seems unlikely but I thought I'd mention it.
So this is for a header bar on a company website.  Logo should be on the left and the menu should be on the right.  It must be responsive.  Here's what I've got so far:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
logo {
    float: none;
    width: 215px;
}


nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

nav ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #171581;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #D60053;
}
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div style="opacity: 1;" class="wrapper">
    <header class="">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="/" class="glyphicon-log-out top-menu">
                    <img src="~/assets/images/sunwavelogo.png" alt="Sunwave Logo" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="hamburger"></div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="top-menu">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="top-menu">Residential &amp; Business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="top-menu">My Accounts Details</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="top-menu faqs active">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="top-menu">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing your CSS like this (note the added dot in `.logo`)

```
.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 215px;
}
nav {
    margin-left: 215px;
}
```

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 215px;
}
nav {
    margin-left: 215px;
}
nav ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #171581;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #D60053;
}
```

```html
<div style="opacity: 1;" class="wrapper">
    <header class="">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="/" class="glyphicon-log-out top-menu">
                    <img src="~/assets/images/sunwavelogo.png" alt="Sunwave Logo" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="hamburger"></div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="top-menu">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="top-menu">Residential &amp; Business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="top-menu">My Accounts Details</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="top-menu faqs active">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="top-menu">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems in your code:

- `logo` in your css should be `.logo` to refer to the class of the logo.
- The property `float:none` should be set to `float:left;` so it should be correctly floated.
- And for the nav you shouldn't specify a `width:100%` because it will be forced to take the whole width of the header, you need to set it to `auto` for example.

**This is a working snippet:**

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  width: 215px;
}
nav {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
nav ul {
  height: auto;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #171581;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: #D60053;
}
```

```html
<div style="opacity: 1;" class="wrapper">
  <header class="">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="/" class="glyphicon-log-out top-menu">
          <img src="~/assets/images/sunwavelogo.png" alt="Sunwave Logo" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="hamburger"></div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="top-menu">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="top-menu">Residential &amp; Business</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="top-menu">My Accounts Details</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="top-menu faqs active">FAQ</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="top-menu">Contact us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Your code was badly formatted.I have formatted it.

2..logo should be set to "float:left".

3..container should have"overflow:hidden"

I have also made Your li straight.(I have made it in one line )

This contains your html formatted code,Css which You may need to change as well as add

```
<div style="opacity: 1;" class="wrapper">
  <header class="">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="/" class="glyphicon-log-out top-menu">
          <img src="~/assets/images/sunwavelogo.png" alt="Sunwave Logo" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="hamburger">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="top-menu">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="top-menu">Residential &amp; Business</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="top-menu">My Accounts Details</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="top-menu faqs active">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="top-menu">Contact us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Your css code:

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
header{
  width:700px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right:100px;
}

.hamburger {
  /* float: left; */
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Hope This Is what You had expected